# Self-consistent solution to an Ordinary Differential Equation with two components

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation
$$
x'(t) = f(x(t), t) + g(x(t))
$$
for which I know the solution of $y'(t) = f(t, y(t))$ which reads $y(t) = F(t, y(0))$. I believe I can write the solution of this differential equation in a self-consistent way, as
$$
x(t) = F(t, x(0)) + \int_0^t F\left(t-s, g(x(s))\right) \,\mathrm{d} s
$$
**Question:** Is this formula correct? If so, does it have a name? And where can I find more information on this?

Thanks !

Comment: Substitute it and see what pops out!

Comment: What do you mean? Should I reinsert $x(t)$ into the integral? I know that by differentiating the self-consistent equation, I think I get back to the former differential equation (unless I'm missing something). I am mostly for references on these type of objects.

Answer (score 1):

We can check your solution thanks to [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{x}(t) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(F(t,x(0)) + \int_0^t F(t-s, g(x(s))) \,\mathrm{d}s\right) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \dot{F}(t,x(0)) + F(0,g(x(t))) + \int_0^t \dot{F}(t-s, g(x(s))) \,\mathrm{d}s \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   f(t,x(t)) + F(0,g(x(t))) + \int_0^t \dot{F}(t-s, g(x(s))) \,\mathrm{d}s \\
   &\neq& \displaystyle
   f(t,x(t)) + g(x(t)) \\
\end{array}
$$
However, starting from your ansatz, we can guess the solution by inspection and find :
$$
x(t) = F(t,x(0)) + \int_0^t F(s,g(x(0))) \,\mathrm{d}s
$$

---

**N.B. :** $F$ is not the antiderivative of $f$ but its *flow* $-$ perhaps you already know it, but that is to be sure.